# Site not rendering correctly on different browser versions and operating systems

Tags: css, cross-browser, flexbox, compatibility, tablet

I am currently developing a website and I am having some issues with browser compatibility but I am not sure what/where the problem is so I was hoping to get some help narrowing it down.

Generally, everything seems to be okay with the latest browser versions, but I want to be able to support at least a few versions back as well, not just the most up to date versions.

A lot of the website is arranged using Flexbox, so I thought this might be the issue, but I have included all of the vendor prefixes I know of and have seen no change (see example).

```
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-direction: column;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
-webkit-box-direction: normal;
-ms-flex-direction: column;
flex-direction: column;
-webkit-align-items: center;
-webkit-box-align: center;
-ms-flex-align: center;
align-items: center;
```

Here is the link to the site: [development.seanbaines.com/bobbys_sportsbar](http://development.seanbaines.com/bobbys_sportsbar)

So far, everything is rendered fine on:

### MacBook Pro (Mid-2009)

*(OS X El Capitan 10.11.6)*:

- Chrome - version 57.0.2987.98 (64-bit)
- Safari - version 10.0.3 (11602.4.8.0.1)
- Firefox - version 52.0 (64-bit)

### iPhone 5c

*(iOS version 10.2.1 (14D27))*:

- Safari - version 602.1

### Asus ZenPad 8.0 z380c

*(Android version 5.0.2)*:

- Chrome - version 56.0.2924.87

### Samsung Galaxy Note 8.0 gt-n5110

*(Android version 4.4.2)*:

- Chrome version 56.0.2924.87

---

These have been the problems:

### Asus ZenPad 8.0 z380c

*(Android version 5.0.2)*:

Chrome - version 43.0.2357.93

Issues:

- Images not displayed

### Samsung Galaxy Note 8.0 gt-n5110

*(Android version 4.4.2)*

Chrome version 55.0.2883.91

Issues:

- Wrong font for logo
- No map
- No social links displayed

### iPad (old, but not sure which model)

*(iOS - version 9.3.5)*

Safari - *version unknown*

Issues:

- Images not displayed
- Body copy squashed together

---

Here are some images from the Asus and Samsung tablets:
[image: Samsung Galaxy Note - Wrong logo font]

[image: Samsung Galaxy Note - No map or social links]

[image: Asus Zenpad - No images]

Sorry for the long post, but wanted to give adequate information. If anyone has any ideas on what the problems might be and how to fix them, that would be amazing.

Thanks!

Comment: Try this: https://www.browserstack.com/ and it's help you to emulate different browser & device's. Also you can use firebug & can find out what happen.

Comment: @OmarFaruque Thanks. Used browserstack before but never heard of firebug. Will look it up and check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox is known to have a few issues even on the latest browsers. You should take a look at this repository and implement it: https://github.com/luisrudge/postcss-flexbugs-fixes
You should also take a look at autoprefixer that prevent you to have to write all the vendor prefixes: https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer

The setup can be a little bit complicated for beginners but you should find tutorials quite easily!

Comment: Thanks, they look really useful. Will have a look at both of them. It definitely was a pain writing out all of the prefixes!